# How to boot other operating systems from GRUB rescue mode?

Tags: grubrescue

I want to uninstall Ubuntu 16.04 completely from my PC. When I deleted the partition, this problem occurred when I botted again.

Comment: Assuming you have another OS installed, boot with Live USB and run boot-repair

Comment: I don't have a live cd or usb